# Did Joseph have other children?

Tags: genesis, joseph

In Genesis 48:6 (NASB)

> But your children that you have fathered after them shall be yours; they shall be called by the names of their brothers in their inheritance.

Did Joseph have other children apart from Ephraim and Manasseh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two matters raised here in Gen 48:6 -

- Why did Jacob adopt Joseph's sons, and
- Did Joseph have any further children

**A. Jacob adopting Joseph's sons**

The Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary answers this quite succinctly:

> 5. **thy two sons**, Ephraim and Manasseh—It was the intention of the aged patriarch to adopt Joseph's sons as his own, thus giving him a
>    double portion. The reasons for this procedure are stated (1Ch 5:1,
>    2).
>
> **are mine**—Though their connections might have attached them to Egypt and opened to them brilliant prospects in the land of their
> nativity, they willingly accepted the adoption (Heb 11:25).

See appendix below about the double portion

**B. Joseph's further children??**

Benson answers this quite well -

> **Genesis 48:6**. Thy issue after them — The Scriptures nowhere mention,
> nor does it appear that Joseph had any more children than these. But
> Jacob speaks this on supposition that he might, and in case he should
> have any more. Shall be thine — Shall be reputed as thy children and
> my grand- children, and shall not have any distinct share of my
> present and future inheritance, but shall have a part of their
> brethren’s lot in such manner and proportion as thou shalt think fit.

**APPENDIX - Double portion**

The birthright had several provisions that would normally have been inherited by Reuben; however, Reuben disqualified himself by his incestuous actions from the birthright, Gen 49:4.  Therefore the birthright provision were distributed among the other tribes as follows:

- Priesthood went to Levi
- family leader and ancestor of Messiah went to Judah
- Double portion of land went to Joseph